# Shell Script, iterating over a folder

Tags: bash, unix, shell, shell-script

I have very basic shell scripting knowledge.

I have photos under `original` folder on many different folder like this

```
folder
  + folder1
    + original
  + folder2
    + original
  + folder3
    + original
  + folder4
    + original
```

Using `mogrify` I'm trying to create thumbs under a `thumb` folder following a structure to this.

```
folder
  + folder1
    + original
    + thumb
  + folder2
    + original
    + thumb
  + folder3
    + original
    + thumb
  + folder4
    + original
    + thumb
```

I'm a little lost in how to write the shell script that may iterate through it. I'm ok giving   mogrify its settings but I don't complete understand how to tell the script to go iterate each folder to run the mogrify command.

Comment: How many files are we talking about--total?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use a for loop where you will have issues if there are spaces in any of the file paths, you can use find to recursively look under a directory and take an action on all files whose name matches a pattern. If all files will need to be affected, just leave out the -name option or customize it to fit.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.png" -exec mogrify {} +
```

To make better use of mogrify's options, you can use xargs.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.png" | xargs mogrify -path /path/to/thumbnails
```

Comment: Good point. I like it.  Is there a modification to this that would generate the resulting directory structure that the OP desires?  mogrify will be run in the current directory.

Comment: Yes, mogrify takes an output parameter as shown in ephsmith's solution: `mogrify -path ./thumbnails/ $f`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you'll see a great deal of variation in the responses you'll receive.  There are more than a few ways to do it.  The following approach simply uses `ls` to list directories in the *current directory*.  It then changes to that directory to get a list of png files (modify to suit).  For each of the png files, mogrify is called.

Basically, you'll need to

1. Copy this into a text editor.
2. Modify the line containing mogrify command to suit.
3. For simplicity, save it as a plain-text file to the directory in which you want to run it.
4. Set the execute bit for the file with `chmod +x /path/to/scriptname`
5. Run it from the directory with `./scriptname`

Script below:

```
DIRS="$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d)"

for d in $DIRS
do
    cd $d
    FILES="$(find . -name '*.png')"
    for f in $FILES
    do
    mogrify -path ./thumbnails/ $f
    done
    cd ..
done
```